# A <textarea> for codes

Tags: php, textarea

I want to be able to get users to provide their own code

First of all, I already have "$userid 've got the value:

```
$usrid = mysql_result($res, 0, "id");
```

After a String of the code and let it take userid $ amount:

```
$string = "<!--cod Start-->
<iframe src="http://mysite.ir/code.php?id=$usrid" name="Noruz" width=250 height=250"></iframe>
<!--cod END--> ";
```

After I echo the  that they copy

```
    echo("<center><p><br>کد شما<br><textarea>$string</textarea></p></center>");
```

But it still did not values

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

Hamid,
It should be:

```
$string = '<!--cod Start-->
<iframe src="http://mysite.ir/code.php?id='. $usrid .'" name="Noruz" width=250 height=250"></iframe>
<!--cod END--> ';
```